# Seeding database from engine root fails to locate db/seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins

After creating a new Rails 3.1 gem plugin via:

```
rails plugin new core --full
```

I am trying to seed the database with:

```
rake db:seed
```

I am running into the following error:

```
rake aborted!
can't convert nil into String
```

Moving the seeds.rb file into the test/dummy/db directory seems to resolve the problem.  Is there any way to let the db:seed task know what the current working directory is, or where to find the seeds.rb file?  The ideal solution would be to keep seeds.rb within my engines db directory

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I made a mistake naming my seed file "seed.rb", not "seeds.rb". Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your engine as

```
rails plugin new core --full --mountable
```

You should now be able to do `rake db:migrate` from your engine root.  If it's not a mountable engine, since the generators would typically deploy to your app (in this case test/dummy or spec/dummy) it makes sense that the rake task would be run from the host application.

Comment: This isn't a mountable engine, but rather a foundation engine. The engine has it's own models and migrations. Best practices would indicate that initial data be put in a seed file rather than in a migration from my understanding.  With this limitation, my seed data only exists within the dummy application and is not available in production to the including application.  It would be nice for engines to allow seeding with a command such as "rake {engine_name}:db:seed"

Comment: Well you would be able to achieve that if you compared the difference between one generated simply as `--full` and `--mountable`.  You'll find it creates a *db* folder as well as a `Rakefile` at the level of your engine.  You can remove whatever extra cruft it adds that makes it "mountable" =)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a seeds.rb in my dummy/db directory. In the seeds.rb file I created, I just added:

```
require File.expand_path('../../../../db/seeds.rb', __FILE__)
```

This basically extends and runs the seeds.rb file in the engines db directory.

**Please Note**

1. I am using both --full and --mountable and `rake db:seed` did not work (plus various other things)
2. I am using rspec for my tests, so my dummy is in the spec/dummy directory of the engine
3. I modified my rake and rails so that I could get rspec working

useful posts I have found

1. [rails 3.1 engines with rspec](http://www.bsodmike.com/2011/09/22/howto-rails-3-1-engines-with-rspec/)

Hope this helps

Comment: That's a decent idea although it won't work once you try to put it into production as you will be running within a client application without the custom seeds.rb.  In the meantime, I've put this data in migrations, although I don't think that should be best practice.